# Why did Alexandre Dumas use Greek names for the three musketeers?

Tags: french-language, name-significance, alexandre-dumas-pere, the-three-musketeers

In the 1844 novel *The Three Musketeers* by French novelist Alexandre Dumas there are three musketeers who are named Aramis, Athos, and Porthos.

But they are French. Why did Alexandre Dumas choose Greek names for them?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Dumas based *The Three Musketeers* very loosely on the fictionalized memoirs of [Charles de Batz de Castelmore d’Artagnan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_de_Batz_de_Castelmore_d%27Artagnan) (1611–1673), in which:

> Celui que j’accostai s’appelloit Portos, & étoit voisin de mon Père de deux ou trois lieuës. Il avoit encore deux Frères dans la Compagnie, dont l’un s’appelloit Athos, & l’autre Aramis.
>
> The man that I had accosted was called Porthos, and he was my father’s neighbour of two or three leagues. He had two brothers† in the company [of musketeers], of whom one was called Athos, and the other Aramis.
>
> <sub>Gatien de Courtilz de Sandras (1700). [*Memoires de Monsieur d’Artagnan*, p. 14](https://archive.org/details/memoiresdemrdar01sandgoog/page/13/mode/2up). Cologne: Pierre Marteau.</sub>
>
> <sub>† “brothers” means “close friends” here.</sub>

All three of these musketeers were from Gascony, and their names are French or Basque:

- “Porthos” was [**Isaac de Porthau**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_de_Porthau) (1617–1712), or in some sources, his brother Jean. The name is French:

  > The Porthaus were an ancient family of Béarn, taking their name from one of the old *porthaux* or *portes* (small frontier towers resembling the [peel-towers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peel_tower) of the British Border) with which the French and Spanish Pyrenees were studded.
  >
  > <sub>Gerald Brenan (1899).  ‘[The Real d’Artagnan](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_EPeuhhUVAg8C/page/204/mode/2up)’. In *Macmillan’s Magazine*, volume 80, p. 205.</sub>

  Brenan says that although Dumas kept the *name* “Porthos” for d’Artagnan’s friend, he based his *character* on another figure (M. Besmaux) in the *Memoires*.
- “Athos” was [**Armand d’Athos**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armand_d%27Athos) (1615–1643). The name is from the village of [Athos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athos-Aspis) in Gascony, which may derive from the Basque name *Ato*. The resemblance to Mount Athos in Greece is coincidental.
- “Aramis” was [**Henri d’Aramitz**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_d%27Aramitz) (1620–1655? 1674?), who was lord of [Aramits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aramits) in Gascony. The name of the village is Basque, from *aran* meaning “valley”.

The OP wonders in comments why Dumas did not use the spellings “Porthau” and “Aramitz”, but Dumas was not in a position to do this, as he was working from the *Memoires*, where the spellings are “Portos” or “Porthos” and “Aramis” respectively. As for the spellings in the *Memoires*, no-one knows exactly what sources de Sandras drew on for this work, which was written a couple of decades after the death of its subject. Possibly de Sandras had interviewed people who had known d’Artagnan (“il y a plusieurs personnes qui l’ont connu”, [p. 2](https://archive.org/details/memoiresdemrdar01sandgoog/page/n9/mode/2up)), in which case he would have had to deduce the spellings from the pronunciations, or possibly he had access to documents such as letters that were contemporary with his subject (“je rassemble ici quantité de morceaux que j’ai trouvez parmi ses papiers après sa mort”, [p. 2](https://archive.org/details/memoiresdemrdar01sandgoog/page/n9/mode/2up)), but if so, these must have been from the mid-17th-century, which was before French spelling was standardized: the [*Dictionnaire de l'Académie française*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionnaire_de_l%27Acad%C3%A9mie_fran%C3%A7aise) only began to be published in 1687. We must be careful not to project modern ideas about spelling (that is, that every name has a single correct spelling) back into a period when [people did not always](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelling_of_Shakespeare%27s_name#Shakespeare%27s_signatures) spell their *own* name consistently. In French, the spellings “Portos”, “Porthos”, “Porthau”, and “Porthaux” indicate similar sounds, so 17th-century writers may simply have picked the spelling they liked best, and this may well have been for Latinizing or Graecizing reasons.

Comment: And in the novel, [*Porthos*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porthos) and [*Aramis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aramis) are aliases, given when they joined the musketeers, probably because they had reasons for not giving their real names (Aramis had killed somebody in a duel; duels were illegal). We never learn Porthos's real name, but Aramis's real name was René.

Comment: But Dumas had a reason for Greekicizing the names for sure. Why didn't he keep Porthau and Aramitz? Why did he turn them into Porthos and Aramis?

Comment: According to the passage quoted, it was the real d'Artagnan who did so!

Comment: So basically, he didn't use Greek names, or 'Greekicized' names, he wrote down French or Basque names in a specific spelling that just so happens to look Greek. 

(Of course, knowing how languages evolve, there might be something more here, but sometimes a cigar is just a cigar.)

Comment: For the record, I'm French and I was very puzzled when I first read the title of this question: it had never crossed my mind before that Athos, Aramis and Porthos "sounded Greek"

Comment: "Porthos" and "Athos" do look somewhat Greek—they've got "th" (which is rare in words of Latin origin), and the "os" ending resembles the Greek second declension. Compare "Korinthos".

Comment: @Stef - Doesn't someone in the book say "Athos is not the name of a man, it's the name of a mountain!"? I remember being puzzled when I first read an English translation, as I had not then heard of Mount Athos.

Comment: @KateBunting [Book 1, chapter 13](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1257/pg1257-images.html#chap13).

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, Athos is a Greek mountain and Portos is a delicious Portuguese wine. I had always thought Aramis was the odd one out, his name seemingly not meaning anything. For this reason I was very satisfied when [an asteroid was named after him](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/(227962)_Aramis).

Comment: @Gareth: in modern French, *Porthos* is pronounced with an /s/, but *Porthau* has no /s/. However, the pronunciation of final consonants in French has been in flux for quite some time, so it's possible they were homonyms when Dumas wrote *Les Trois Mousquetaires.*

Comment: @PeterShor Fair point—now removed.

Comment: @Buurman That would be Hellenized. For the origin of the names, this article in Le Figaro is pretty great and since no one is paying me, I ain't translating it. :) https://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/actu-des-mots/les-trois-mousquetaires-d-ou-viennent-les-noms-d-athos-porthos-et-aramis-20230405